# How to increase volume of a track on OSX

Tags: macos, audio, mp3, m4a

I'm looking for some software to increase the volume of a track that I have in m4a (but I know how to convert it to whatever) for osx.  Can anyone name such a thing?

I tried macMP3gain but that doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: You made the m4a file?  With what software?  There may be solutions within the software you used to make the initial m4a file to increase the volume.

Comment: I made the m4a with djay

Comment: DJay appears to have an Auto-Gain feature.  This most likely normalizes any major audio differences and levels out different tracks to produce a single, even level.  I would disable this feature and boost the gain as much as possible (without distortion) when you output to M4A.  See if that gets you louder exports.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).  It's an open-source cross-platform audio editor.  I haven't used it for years, but normalizing a signal or at least amplifying it is one of the most basic things you can do.  There ought to be a very accessible feature in Audacity to do it.